# Best way of handling multiple object instances

Tags: kotlin, data-class

Due in part to the fact that I cannot create data classes without parameters in Kotlin, I use `object`s for those cases, e.g.

```
sealed class Node {
  object Leaf : Node()
  data class Branch(val left:Node, val right:Node) : Node()
}
```

The issue is that sometimes, I end up with multiple instances of the `Leaf` class. Obviously this should not generally happen, but it occurs when serializing and deserializing with some frameworks and with some test cases.

Now, you might argue that I should fix those cases, but it's hard to know where they might be, and not always possible or desirable to modify the deserialization semantics of frameworks.

As such, I want *all* instances of my `object`s to act as the same value, much like a parameter-less `data class` would (or a parameterless `case class` in Scala).

My best solution so far is the following, included in every `object` I create that might encounter this issue:

```
object SaneLeaf {
    override fun hashCode() = javaClass.hashCode()
    override fun equals(other: Any?) = other?.javaClass == javaClass
}
```

Obviously, this is verbose and error prone, since it doesn't seem possible to abstract away those implementations to an interface. A super-class would work in cases where the object doesn't need to extend another class, but that's often not the case.

Alternatively, I can create a data class with a `Nothing` parameter. But that seems like even more of a hack.

How have others dealt with this issue? Are there plans to add `hashCode` and `equals` implementations to objects that follow the presumed semantics of those classes (all instances should be equal / same hashCode)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe having multiple instances of an `object`'s underlying class is really an issue you should fix, but there's a simpler workaround that allows you to have the equality semantics you described.

You can define an abstract class that performs the equality logic and make the `sealed` class inherit from it, like this:

```
abstract class SingletonEquality {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean =
        this::class.objectInstance != null && other?.javaClass == this.javaClass || 
        super.equals(other)

    override fun hashCode(): Int = 
        if (this::class.objectInstance != null) 
            javaClass.hashCode() else 
            super.hashCode()
}
```

And the usage:

```
sealed class Node : SingletonEquality() {
    object Leaf : Node()
    data class Branch(val left:Node, val right:Node) : Node()
}
```

Here, `Leaf` will inherit the `equals` implementation from `SingletonEquality` and get compared just the way you want.

Comment: can you imagine the situation when there are 2 or more singletons?

Comment: @ViktorYakunin, OP says: `I end up with multiple instances of the Leaf class.`, seemingly after serialization and de-serialization.

Comment: this is very interesting topic, want to see this in action :)

Comment: @ViktorYakunin, here's a demo: https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/40c5d3e4fa2cf66a4293cc4277b744bc

Comment: Thanks, so Reflection, Serialization what else is there?

Comment: Thanks for this... I didn't think of the fact that hashCode/equals will be overridden by the data classes. I'd love to see a more "official" discussion of this as well, if there is one. Otherwise, perhaps I should open a KT ticket?

Comment: This page says that `data` classes override `equals`/`hashCode` when the implementations in the super types are not final: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#data-classes

Comment: @hotkey Yeah, indeed. That's why this works and is so clever. I thought it wouldn't at first because it would overwrite the semantics of the data class equals/hashCode, but it doesn't, which is great. It seems to me that this should be the default behavior for all kotlin objects.